# how to stop htaccess rewrite rule from rewriting all urls

Tags: php, .htaccess

i am having a mod rewrite problem and i am new to htaccess not because i tried to do a mod_rewrite and link i try to open assumes that i am in profile.php
heres my code

`.htaccess` file contents

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404,/
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z\A-Z\0-9\_\-]+)$ profile.php?username=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-z\A-Z\0-9\_\-]+)/$ profile.php?username=$1
```

I just wanted localhost/qwerty to display profile.php anything else should show the normal page and if it does not exists it shows a 404 error



`profile.php` contents

```
<?php
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "databasename");
if(!$conn) {        
    die("connection failed". mysqli_connect_error());
}

if(!isset($_GET['username'])) {
    header("location:./login,/?error=true");
} else {   
     $username = $_GET['username'];
     $quer="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";

     $result = $conn->query($quer);
     if(!$row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo 'user does not exist';
      } else {
          echo 'user exists';
      }
}
?>
```

NOW MY FILE TREE

```
                                               htdocs(xampp)
                                                   |
 =======================================================================================
 |         |          |              |                       |                         |
login,    404,     style.css      profile.php              index.php               .htacccess
```

Now the problem is that none of the style sheets (or the javascript files) load , all the pages on http://localhost are now assumed to be `profile.php`, and in `profile.php`  $_GET['username'] displays `PROFILE.PHP' instead of 'USER123'
 Just to be clear i want it that if http://localhost/login, is the url then login, loads(i even added a comma at the end of login to make the .htaccess not to look at login as a username, but that doesn't work)

Comment: What is the _exact_ URL you are requesting? `/qwerty` or `/qwerty/` (with a trailing slash)? You have a rewrite rule for both for some reason. Your example shows a URL without a trailing slash, however, if you are requesting a URL _with_ a trailing slash and you are using _relative_ URLs to your static resources then it will fail to load your CSS and JS files. See the following question in the Webmasters stack if this is the case: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86450/htaccess-rewrite-url-leads-to-missing-css

Comment: @MrWhite i have cleared my browser cache and those are the 3 rules that are in my htaccess

Comment: @MrWhite any of the urls will do (either /qwerty/ or /qwerty)

Comment: @webing Ah, missed it at first - but you have a "bug" in the regex which results in it matching the dot (`.`). I've added an answer. (You appear to be posting as a different user?)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^([a-z\A-Z\0-9\_\-]+)$ profile.php?username=$1
> ```

The problem is with the regex - you shouldn't be backslash escaping the literal `0` inside the character class. In doing so you are increasing the character range (from "char code 0" instead of "char code 48" - a literal zero) and so includes the dot (`.` - character code 46). This results in `profile.php?username=<something>` (and any file) getting further rewritten resulting in `$_GET['username']` having the value `profile.php` - as you've stated.

Remove *all* the backslash escapes...

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?username=$1 [L]
```

Providing the hyphen (`-`) is at the end (or beginning) of the character class, it does not need to be escaped.

However, this still won't work for `login` and `404` URLs (unless you append a comma to the filename). Although this highlights another potential problem. These represent physical files so should have a file extension. By omitting the file extension, Apache won't necessarily know how to handle/process it.  By default, it will simply be sent back to the client - unprocessed - without a `Content-Type` header and then left for the browser to interpret - probably as text/html, but could be text/plain (HTML is exposed to the client), depending on the browser.

If `login` is required to be processed as PHP then it should be called `login.php`. If you want to be able to access it from the client as `/login` (no extension) then you need an additional rewrite directive in `.htaccess`, just as you did for `/qwerty`. This directive needs to go *before* your existing directive in order to avoid conflicts. (You can't have a *username* called "login" unless you change the format of your `/qwerty` URL to identify this as a user.)

`404` is an error document and shouldn't be directly accessible anyway. So this should simply be `404.php` (or `404.html`) and referenced as such in the `ErrorDocument` directive. (You had also appended a trailing slash `/404,/`, so this wouldn't have served the file anyway.)

For example:

```
Options -MultiViews

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^login$ login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ profile.php?username=$1 [L]
```

The shorthand character class `\w` is the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.